# Hudson shell problems

Tags: shell, hudson, if-statement

I'm trying to run the following code in hudson bash (hudson version 1.395):

```
if [ false == false ]; then echo true; fi
```

If I type this in bash shell, it works (I know that false is truly a string, but I need to compare strings). However, this is hudson output:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/tomcat/temp/hudson382382245103929499.sh
+ [ false == false ]
[: 1: false: unexpected operator
Finished: SUCCESS
```

My suspect is that hudson is not running bash. Either way, is there some way I can do this?

Thanks,
Rafael

Comment: Your clue is in `[workspace] $ /bin/sh ...`: `sh` is not Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard equality operator is `=` *not* `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921057/shell-script-working-fine-on-one-server-but-not-on-another) with "=="